# Why packing widgets into frames instead of directly packing them into the root window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm learning Python by building an airplane ticket app. I'm currently working on learning TkInter for the GUI, and I want to know why I have to create a container (frame) instead of just putting everything in `root = Tk()` which seems to work.

Also, isn't `ttk` part of `tkinter`, therefore I shouldn't have to have the 2nd line (`from tkinter import ttk`)?

Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root)
root.title("AirTix")

flight_title = Label(frame, text = "Flights").grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could just pack your widgets directly into the `Tk` window, but packing them into a frame eventually gives you more flexibility, if you want to create more complex layouts. For example, if you wanted to move a few widgets together, you can simply move the frame that contains them. `ttk` is a sub-module of `tkinter`, so you have to import it as you're doing.

Comment: Thanks! If I use a grid, is the frame necessary?

Comment: It may be. As you learn more about "laying out" widgets on the window, specifically the "grid" and "pack" (and eventually the "place") layout managers, you will learn that you can create many combinations.

Comment: You should use `Frame` for every group of widgets that has a meaning I think. For example, you can create numeral buttons for a calculator and put them in a frame. Then you can use that same frame with a calling app perhaps. Also the moving thing, It would be drastically harder to move the numeral buttons, one by one or with a loop alike, if they're not contained by a parent widget, be it frame or whatever.

Comment: `Tk` is the _main window_ of GUI, that has its limitations. Whereas a `Frame` usually represents a group of widgets, packed together for convenience. You can choose to put that frame in the main window or you can choose another.

Comment: @Nae: what do you mean that the main window "has its limitations"? What limitations are you referring to?

Comment: @BryanOakley Well limitations such as you can't put an instance of it inside another window for example. Or if you want to replace the GUI whilst the program is still running with another window, it would be pretty inconvenient to change, as opposed to just replacing a frame inside the widget is what I meant by limitations mostly.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know why I have to create a container (frame) instead of just putting everything in `root = Tk()` which seems to work.

You do not have to create a container. Whatever tutorial or book is telling you that you must is wrong. There's nothing wrong with creating everything in the root window.

That being said, for anything but the most trivial of apps, it helps *tremendously* to organize your widgets in logical groups, with each logical group being a frame (or, perhaps, a Canvas or PanedWindow). This gives you the flexibility to use the best geometry manager (`pack`, `place`, or `grid`) for each section.

For example, it makes sense to have a toolbar that is a frame with a bunch of buttons packed left-to-right. The same might be true for a bottom status bar. The main body might be a frame with widgets arranged in a grid.

`grid` can be a bit more complicated to use, and `pack` excels at placing widgets either in a single horizontal row (toolbar or status bar), or column (toolbar on top, status bar on bottom, main area in the middle.

> Also, isn't `ttk` part of tkinter, therefore I shouldn't have to have the 2nd line (`from tkinter import ttk`)?

Even though ttk is part of tkinter, it does not get imported when you import everything from tkinter. Many python packages are this way, with sub-modules that must be explicitly imported.

Further, it's bad practice to use a wildcard import. Instead of doing this:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
```

... it's arguably better to do it like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
```

With the former, you end up polluting the global namespace with a bunch of things you may or may not use. With the latter, you import exactly one thing. Plus, it makes your code more self-documenting because it makes it crystal clear when you are expecting to use an object or class from the tk package.